# Form value being posted with Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

(The site i am going to talk about can be accessed at http://www.akbrowser.tk/preset.html )

The portion of the site that I am going to talk about is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Preset AKBrowser</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="000000">
<center>
<table bgcolor="00FFFF" width="50%">
<tr><td>
<br>
<br>
<br>
AKBrowser 
<br>
<br>
<form id="akbrowser">
URL: <input type="text" name="aouwygbaiusvsjkraeiwc" value="http://www." />   
<br>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Submit"  onClick="postakbrowser(document.akbrowser.aouwygbaiusvsjkraeiwc.value)">
</form>
<br><br>
<script type="text/javascript">
function postakbrowser(x) 
{
document.write("http://www.akbrowser.tk/?aouwygbaiusvsjkraeiwc=" + "x");
}
</script>
</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

(If you visited the webpage, the part above is everything above the horizontal line)

So, as you can see, I am trying to make a form, such that when the submit button is clicked, a javascript function (called postakbrowser() ) runs.

Let us say that "cheese" was inputted in the form

as you can see, I want the string "http://www.akbrowser.tk/?aouwygbaiusvsjkraeiwc=cheese" to be posted below the form

I don't understand why it doesn't work!

Can I have some help? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need JavaScript for that. HTML forms do all that hard work for you by default.

Just put this as your form tag:

```
<form name="input" action="script_name" method="GET">
```

And then you can simply use the submit input tag to handle the event:

```
<input type="submit" Value="Submit" />
```

Comment: I tried that, but it leads to a 404 error. I think it is interpreting my postakbrowser(document.akbrowser.aouwygbaiusvsjkraeiwc.value) as a link, which it isn't, so it goes to a 404 error. After omitting the quotation marks (so it looked like action=postakbrowser(document.akbrowser.aouwygbaiusvsjkraeiwc.value) ), it didn't do anything, just like before

Answer (score 1):

why are you doing that

```
document.write("http://www.akbrowser.tk/?aouwygbaiusvsjkraeiwc=" + "x");
```

I think you only have to do this

```
document.write("http://www.akbrowser.tk/?aouwygbaiusvsjkraeiwc=" + x);
```

give a try

Comment: Yeah. thanks, I fixed it, but it still didn't do what I wanted it to do.